# I have a self signed certificate in nodejs. When I have added the certificate key and when i try to run it the node is giving the error shown below

Tags: node.js, express, https

```
var express = require('express')
    //Required for cluster 
    ,
    cluster = require('cluster')
    //Required for countting the cpu cores 
    ,
    numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length,
    socketio = require('socket.io'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    https = require('https'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    app = connect(),
    sslOptions, server, port = 1111,
    path = require('path');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
app.use(form({
    keepExtensions: true
}));


sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt')
};

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    for (var i = 1; i < numCPUs; ++i)
        console.log('hi');
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log("The Master is forked");
    });
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        logger.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });
} else {
    var app = express();
    var server = require('https').createServer(app);

    // all environments
    // app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1111);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.get('/', routes.index);
    app.get('/users', user.list);

    server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Listening on https://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
    });
```

The error which i am getting is

```
Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server,
please use:

  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();


/home/lilac/revanth/app.js:25
app.use(form({ keepExtensions: true }));
        ^
ReferenceError: form is not defined
    at Object. (/home/lilac/revanth/app.js:25:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the variable `form` anywhere.

Also you should replace `express.createServer()` with `express()`

Comment: I have replaced it and it is not giving any error, Instead the code is not moving further.
[lilac@LILAC revanth]$ node app.js
The Master is forked
hi
   info  - socket.io started
Express server listening on port 1111

Comment: What do you mean "the code is not moving further?" You haven't coded anything else to happen. The process should still be open and listening for requests on port 1111 as you've set it up.